# Generate a published date for documents in a SharePoint library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, approval, date

I am very new to SharePoint and I want to automate a creation of a published/approved date for documents when they are approved through the OOTB approval workflow to a major version. From what I have research (which is a lot!) I need to create a new column in my document library to house this information. I have done this and then set up a new list workflow (see first image) to run to check that the document is in the approval status and if this is true, it should put today's date in the published date column. However when I run the workflow it fails as the document need to be checked out for the workflow to update the column (see second image).

Is there a way around this so the document doesn't need to be checked out? Or is there a different method to create a published date for documents?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems the library you are handling is set to require documents to be checked out before they can be edited.

Go library settings>versioning settings have a check on the option below:
[image]